# Triple integral, how to bound the region

Tags: multiple-integral

Given a region, which is bounded below by z=0, and enclosed by x^2+y^2+4z^2=a^2, where a is positive.
I want to know how to bound the region. Which coordinates should I use, cylindrical or spherical? Is there some technics to do this situation?

Comment: Usually when you have three variables power to square, the most common variable change is using spherical coordinates, you can draw the surface to understand better the region and can put the integration limits, but if you are more expert can deduce it form the equation of the surface.

Comment: But what is the method of finding the bound? I mean, in this question for instance, if I simply write x,y, and z in their spherical form, I don't know how to deduce r θ and φ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the surface was $x^2+y^2+z^2 = a^2$, you'd want to use spherical coordinates. Since the surface is $x^2+y^2+(2z)^2 = a^2$ instead, a slight modification yields bounds which are constants. Set $$x = \rho \cos\theta \sin \phi, \quad y = \rho \sin\theta \sin\phi, \quad z = \dfrac{1}{2}\rho \cos\phi.$$

The bounds are $\rho \in [0,a]$, $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$, and $\phi \in [0,\tfrac{\pi}{2}]$ (since $z \ge 0$), and the Jacobian of the transformation (if you need it) is $\tfrac{1}{2}\rho^2\sin\phi$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be theta from 0 to pi/2 and phi from 0 to 2pi?

Comment: It depends what notation you use. In the above, I used $\theta$ as the polar angle and $\phi$ as the azimuthal angle. If you used the opposite notation, you can just switch all the $\theta$'s and $\phi$'s above.